# Does X-AspNet-Version correlate to .NET framework version

Tags: .net, asp.net

If a server is reporting its **HTTP Headers** as:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
```

Can this be used to determine if the .NET framework is End of Life. According to Microsoft .NET framework 4.0 is no longer supported.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/

Answer (score 6):

Apparently not possible from these values. The X-AspNet-Version refers to the common language runtime (CLR) version.

The CLR only translates very roughly to a .NET framework version.

```
CLR version   .NET version
1.0           1.0
1.1           1.1
2.0           2.0, 3.0, 3.5
4             4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8
```

Sources:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed